# Change datagrid row cell foreground colour dynamically wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, foreground

In my WPF project I have a datagrid which has cells bound to different things. Here is the xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Tasks" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding C1}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" Binding="{Binding C2}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column3" Binding="{Binding C3}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column4" Binding="{Binding C4}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column5" Binding="{Binding C5}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column6" Binding="{Binding C6}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column7" Binding="{Binding C7}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column8" Binding="{Binding C8}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Add task" Click="ADDtask_Click" FontSize="11"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

This is my C# code:

```
public Guid 8 { get; }
public string 7 { get; set; }
public string 6 { get; set; }
public string 5 { get; set; }
public string 4 { get; set; }
public string 3 { get; set; }
public string 2 { get; set; }
public string 1 { get; set; }

public Result(string c1, string c2, string c3, string c4, string c5, string c6, string c7, string c8)
{
    this.Identifier = Guid.NewGuid();
    this.8 = c1;
    this.7 = c2;
    this.6 = c3;
    this.5 = c4;
    this.4 = c5;
    this.3 = c6;
    this.2 = c7;
    this.1 = c8;
}

private void Start_Task_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Button button = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender;

    Result task = (Result)button.DataContext;

    if(...)
    {
        ????
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

public string idlestatus = "idle";

private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //this adds the columns to the datagrid
{
    Tasks.Items.Add(new Result(textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text, textbox3.Text, textbox4.Text, textbox5.Text, textbox6.Text, textbox7.Text, idlestatus));
}
```

I want to make an if statement like this:

```
if(task.c1 == "...") {
    cell.Style.Foreground.Color = ...
}
```

How would I be able to do this? I have tried doing something like this:

```
Tasks.CellStyle.Style.Foreground.Color
```

But it doesn't work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Checkout this one: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b9614139-4d12-4fce-a004-b964c9b88af8/wpf-datagrid-change-foreground-color-of-datagrid-cell-if-cell-value-contains-negative-values?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options. Since you don't use auto generated columns you could use the `ElementStyle` property of the `DataGridColumn`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Tasks">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ElementStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text"
                 Value="Error Predicate Text">
          <Setter Property="Foreground"
                  Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="Text"
                 Value="Good Predicate Text">
          <Setter Property="Foreground"
                  Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>

  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"
                        Binding="{Binding C1}"
                        ElementStyle="{StaticResource ElementStyle}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2"
                        Binding="{Binding C2}"
                        ElementStyle="{StaticResource ElementStyle}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

Or use a `DataTrigger`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Tasks">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"
                        Binding="{Binding C1}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2"
                        Binding="{Binding C2}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.Text}"
                     Value="Error Predicate Text" />
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

---

When the trigger should be exclusive to a single cell of a specific column (and not the whole row based on a cell value), you have to use a `MultiDataTrigger` to check the current column header:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Tasks">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"
                        Binding="{Binding C1}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2"
                        Binding="{Binding C2}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Column.Header}"
                       Value="Column1" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding C1}" Value="Error Predicate Text" />
          </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

---

Another solution is to use a `IValueConverter` (or a `IMultiValueConverter` for the same reason as above regarding the `MultiDataTrigger`):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Tasks">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"
                        Binding="{Binding C1}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2"
                        Binding="{Binding C2}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
          <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
              <CellForegroundMultiValueConverter />
            </MultiBinding.Converter>

            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                     Path="Column.Header"/>
            <Binding />
            <Binding Path="HasChanges" />
          </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

**CellForegroundMultiValueConverter.cs**

```
class CellForegroundMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  #region Implementation of IMultiValueConverter

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    var columnHeader = values[0] as string;
    var dataItem = values[1] as Result;
    return columnHeader.Equals("Column1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
           && dataItem.C1.Equals("....", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
      || columnHeader.Equals("Column2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
           && dataItem.C2.Equals("....", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
      ? Brushes.Red
      : Brushes.Black;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotSupportedException();

  #endregion
}
```

Result.cs

```
class Result : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string c1;
  public string C1
  {
    get => this.c1;
    set
    {
      this.c1 = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      this.HasChanegs = true;
    }
  }
  private string c2;
  public string C2
  {
    get => this.c2;
    set
    {
      this.c2 = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      this.HasChanegs = true;
    }
  }

  private bool hasChanges;
  public string HasChanges
  {
    get => this.hasChanges;
    set
    {
      this.hasChanges = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thats great but how would I be able to use IMultiValueConverter  in my c# to change the foreground colour?

Comment: I've added an example implementation of `IMultiValueConverter`. I improved the XAML code (the second `Binding` element) of the last example which uses `Multibinding` too.

Comment: Thanks, it works for when I add a row with that cell text, is there a way to do it so that it auto updates whenever there is a change in text, something maybe along the lines of `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without knowing what you exactly mean, I am still sure it is possible. Can give more details please or try to describe your goal? I don't know where you want to go. Are we still talking about this comparison `dataItem.C1.Equals("....", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`? What enhancement do you want?

Comment: Ive made it so that the the status item is a `NotifyPropertyChanged` and can change values, if it changes to "xxx" from "zzz", it doesnt change the colour, is there any way I could make it to update everytime the string changes. Thanks.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to do. I don't see any status item in your example and don't know how it would relate to the actual equality comparison you are using to change the cell color. I only see a `Result` item. But anyway, if you want the converter to be invoked depending on changes of a specific property, you have to add a binding to this property path to the `MultiBinding`. In case that `Result` would have a property called `Status`, you'd have to add following `Binding`: `<Binding Path="Status" />`. Now changes of the `Result.Status` property would invoke the converter too.

Comment: Or are you talking about the `C1`, `C2` properties?

Comment: Since you have to filter the current column in the converter and each column maps to a property of the `Result` item and you would likely to react on each property's changes, you'd have to add either a binding for all column source properties (e.g. C1 and C2) or (preferred as more extensible) introduce a new property e.g., `HasChanges`. You set this property whenever a column bound property of the item has changed. This will raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `HasChanges` property. When you add this property to the `MultiBinding` it will trigger the invocation of the converter.

Comment: Thanks you have helped me in an unimaginable way, I had been thinking for a good week on how to do this and when I ask on SO, someone helpful like you makes my day. Sorry for not specifying before that I meant c1 instead of status, I forgot that I had changed the details for the question.